# Rails: form_for and radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have the following in my `form_for`

```
<div class="multiple_students">
        <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "Do you teach multiple classes?" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :multiple_classes, 1, checked: @user.multiple_classes?, class: 'multiple_classes', data: { question: 'What is your average class size?' } %> <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "Yes", class: 'multiple_classes' %>
        <%= f.radio_button :multiple_classes, 0, checked: @user.multiple_classes?, class: 'multiple_classes', data: { question: 'How many kids do you teach?' } %> <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "No", class: 'multiple_classes' %>
    </div>
    <div class="number_of_students hide">
        <%= f.label :students %>
        <%= f.text_field :students, :class=>"student_count required digits" %>
    </div>
```

For some reason the "No" is ALWAYS checked even if the `multiple_classes` attribute on the user is selected a true in the database (`multiple_classes` is a boolean type in the database)

Comment: why do you creating two radio buttons? you can do it in a single ain't u?

Comment: @Vinay - can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: do you need two radio buttons in the form or one?

Comment: @Vinay - well, the user can select whether they teach multiple classes or not by selecting a radio button

Comment: I believe @Vinay is suggesting you could just use a single checkbox.

Comment: @Chowlett -- Ah gotcha... sorry, I left out a piece in my explanation. There is some JavaScript tied to the radio buttons for the form to work properly, so I need to use radio buttons

Comment: @dennismonsewicz any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok if you want to use only the radio_buttons, check the following and let me know if thats worked.

```
<%= f.radio_button :multiple_classes, "1", checked: @user.multiple_classes?, class: 'multiple_classes', data: { question: 'What is your average class size?' } %> <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "Yes", class: 'multiple_classes' %>
<%= f.radio_button :multiple_classes, "0", checked: @user.multiple_classes?, class: 'multiple_classes', data: { question: 'How many kids do you teach?' } %> <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "No", class: 'multiple_classes' %>
```

put the `1` and `0` with quotes and try....

Its not an answer... its only an idea...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with always checked "No" is in a typo.

If you revert `@user.multiple_classes?` for `"No"`, checkbox will be unchecked if `@user.multiple_classes?` is `true`, so the next code chunk should work fine:

```
<%= f.radio_button :multiple_classes, 1, checked: @user.multiple_classes?, class: 'multiple_classes', data: { question: 'What is your average class size?' } %> <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "Yes", class: 'multiple_classes' %>
<%= f.radio_button :multiple_classes, 0, checked: !@user.multiple_classes?, class: 'multiple_classes', data: { question: 'How many kids do you teach?' } %> <%= f.label :multiple_classes, "No", class: 'multiple_classes' %>
```